# ImportError: No module named alchemyapi (python)

Tags: python, alchemyapi

I've gone through the [guide](http://www.alchemyapi.com/developers/getting-started-guide/using-alchemyapi-with-python) yet I still seem to get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KVadher\Desktop\test.py", line 782, in <module>
    from alchemyapi import AlchemyAPI
ImportError: No module named alchemyapi
```

The example works fine, but when I try:

```
from alchemyapi import AlchemyAPI
```

I get the above "no module named alchemyapi" error. Is there a pip install I should do in order to install Alchemy properly?

Comment: You have to go inside alchemyapi_python's folder to make the import work.

Comment: Or you include the AlchemyAPI folder into your PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go inside alchemyapi_python's folder to make the import work.